# Bluetooth and Wireless connectivity Issue

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I am new on Linux platform. No idea about it's working and fixing issue.
Today, I have installed linux 20.6 and after installing when I tried to connect with Bluetooth, the issue started to happen:

1. Bluetooth gets disconnected automatically every second.
2. Wireless even shows connected but stops working.

I looked google and tried to get the error log and it shows me this:

```
[ 227.190810] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.0006: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  270.616295] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.0007: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  300.588926] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.0008: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  328.863581] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.0009: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  389.610770] hid-generic 0005:045E:0805.000A: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Mouse [Designer Mouse] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  401.282904] hid-generic 0005:045E:0805.000B: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Mouse [Designer Mouse] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  435.152951] hid-generic 0005:045E:0805.000C: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Mouse [Designer Mouse] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  457.913721] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.000D: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  477.061357] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[  486.247053] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.000E: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  502.584348] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.000F: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
[  532.060614] hid-generic 0005:045E:0806.0010: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v1.20 Keyboard [Designer Keyboard] on 40:f0:2f:68:5e:87
```

I tried to used `rskill` but still not working properly.

Any help will be very appreciated.